# Add controller dialog not listing External Model Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

I am trying to separate entity model from main project so i can reference it from multiple projects. Here are the steps i followed

1. First I created Class Library **STSModels** which has model classes and DBContext.
2. Now i created an ASP.NET MVC 5 project **TestApp**.
3. Added same DBcontext to TestApp's web.config as i created in STSModels.
4. Added STSModels compiled DLL reference to TestApp project.
5. Now i tried to add controller in MVC project, but it is not showing any Model class from STSModels.

[image: Add Controller Screenshot]

I have already tried following with no luck

1. Rebuild TestApp project
2. Confirmed under STSModel project **Metadata Artifact Processing** property set to **Embed in Output Assembly**.
3. Removing and adding STSModels reference multiple times.

However instead of adding reference to STSModels compiled DLL, if i add Project Reference to STSModels project then it is showing all Model Classes. But it is not what i want.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: have you tried clean+rebuild ?

Comment: Ya, i just tried clean+rebuild but still no luck.

Comment: I'm having the same issue..I intially created a model with the project then i moved it to an external model like what you did..

Answer (score 1):

Bingo! Just two steps

1)[Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41204) your Visual studio 2013 to new update 1

2) unload your project from solution explorer then Reload it again.